# Combinatoric putting balls in boxes

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

9 tennis balls, which are numbered 1 through 9 inclusively, will be put into the cylindrical transparent boxes. 2 balls into box A, 3 balls into box B, 4 balls into box C. Further, the balls must be in descending order in the boxes.
In how many different ways can the 9 balls put into the boxes?

I simply think C(9,2)*C(7,3)*C(4,4), but seems absolutely wrong. I really want to comprehend the kind of questions. **Could you explain the answer as explaining to a stupid?**

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that your answer is "absolutely wrong"?

Comment: @user I think I don't satisfy the ordering rule.

Comment: You are in error. Of course this satisfies the rule.

Comment: @user How does sir?

Comment: There is only one way to order any group of chosen balls. Therefore it suffices to choose the members of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Here is the explanation of why.

Please realize this fact:

**Once we put any amount of balls into each box, there is only ONE way to satisfy the order rule of decending.**

For example, if ball 1,3,5 are in box B, there is only one decending order  5,3,1.

Therefore, we just need to take care how these 9 balls are assigned to each  box :
$(C^9_2 \cdot 1 )(C^7_3 \cdot 1)(C^4_4\cdot 1)$ .

Comment: Would you mind glancing at too -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115090/combinatoric-putting-billard-balls-in-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is absolutely correct . Whatever balls you choose for the boxes , they can always be arranged the order you wish , so the number of ways is equal to "selecting" the balls required .

Therefore , your answer ,
$C^9_2 * C^7_3 * C^4_4$ is correct.

Comment: How does it satisfy the ordering rule?

Comment: All the balls are numbered differently , right ? So for example , if you choose 2 balls from the set of balls , they are differently numbered , and hence one is greater and one is smaller . You can easily put them in the boxes in the descending order .

Answer (score 0):

For the first spot you want to choose $2$ balls out of $9$ to go into the first container. Since order doesn't matter we can choose any two balls, and order doesn't matter we will use combinations. Thus, $\binom{9}{2}$.

Now we have $7$ balls left. So we choose $3$ balls to go into the second container, $\binom{7}{3}$. Do the same for the last container, $\binom{4}{4}$.

Your answer is correct! $\binom{9}{2}\cdot \binom{7}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{4}$

Context: $\binom{9}{2}$ is equivalent to $C(9,2)$

Comment: Further, the balls must be in descending order in the boxes. ?? Why is the ordering not matter?

Comment: From what I gathered from the problem, each box with have balls in descending order. For $C(9,2)$, say we choose $9$ and $2$. Then there is $7$ balls left. Then $C(7,3)$ we choose $3$ balls from the $7$, and say the balls are $8,3,1$. Each ball is descending from one another.